# Doctrine MongoDB map reduce reference document

Tags: php, mongodb, doctrine, doctrine-odm

This may be a duplicate of another question I asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35859535/sonata-admin-datagrid-text-search-on-referenced-document) but I'm trying to approach it from a different angle with Mongo map reduce and think

**Situation**

I have two documents

```
Content
    id - ID
    title - String
    contentType - Reference One Tag
    audienceType - Reference One Tag

Tag
    id - ID
    title - String
    type - String
```

I use Tag as a repository for all the various meta-information and split them up by type so, what goes in to Content-contentType is a Tag with type "content-type" and what goes in to Content-audienceType is a Tag with type "audience-type".

The tags are hierarchical but only through the use of a hyphen so, using content-type as an example, for the titles there could be:

```
action
action - swordplay
action - spy
action - space
romance
romance - historical
romance - historical - boy/girl
romance - historical - boy/boy
romance - historical - girl/girl
romance - modern
romance - modern - boy/girl
romance - modern - boy/boy
romance - modern - girl/girl
```

**Issue**

I would like to be able to provide part of the title (which is also indexed if that helps) and find all entries which belong to that "group". For example

If searching for "action", the query would return all documents with references to:

```
action
action - swordplay
action - spy
action - space
```

If searching for "romance - modern". the query would return all documents with references to:

```
romance - modern
romance - modern - boy/girl
romance - modern - boy/boy
romance - modern - girl/girl
```

**Example Documents**

As requested in the comments, here's some examples simplified for the sake of this question:

```
content
{
_id:  ObjectId(1),
title: "Film A",
contentType: ObjectId(11)
audienceType: ObjectId(21)
}
{
_id:  ObjectId(2),
title: "Film B",
contentType: ObjectId(12)
audienceType: ObjectId(21)
}
{
_id:  ObjectId(3),
title: "Film C",
contentType: ObjectId(12)
audienceType: ObjectId(21)
}

Tag
{
_id:  ObjectId(11),
title: "romance - historical",
type: "content-type"
}
{
_id:  ObjectId(12),
title: "romance - historical - boy/girl",
type: "content-type"
}
{
_id:  ObjectId(21),
title: "adults",
type: "audience-type"
}
```

**Attempt**

Because the query is being built using Doctrine, it's also in PHP so I get to put the search value in the map reduce function manually. Not sure if this is the way to go about it though

```
/* Manually setting the value so that it can make sense in question. This should return all the records */
$searchTitle = 'romance - historical';
$queryBuilder
->where('function() {
    return this.contentType.title.search("'.$searchTitle.'");
}');
```

When I perform the above though, Doctrine (through the resultatnt exception) always complains that what I'm trying to search on is undefined. Please can someone enlighten me, MapReduce is a whole new bowl of fish for me

Comment: What does the document look like in MongoDB? It's really unclear as to on what and where the search needs to happen. Just show us the data structure from the relevant collection. Sounds like a regular expression search to me, but the explanation is not really clear.

Comment: `->where` is barely wrapper for `$where` query operator, for documentation on how to use map/reduce with ODM please see its [documentation](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-mongodb-odm/en/latest/reference/map-reduce.html), also [MongoDB's docs](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/map-reduce/) are helpful for grasping the concept of map/reduce.